# Removing lines from txt file, where line doesn't match string

Tags: regex, lines

I have a `.txt` file, with lots of lines in it. I have a procedure to fill up a database, using this textfile. But I only want to insert the lines where the string from position `67 to 70` matches `772`. I cannot change the procedure to read the file, I have to change the file itself.

So in fact, I want to remove all lines from the txt-file where the string on position `67 to 70`, doesn't match `772`.

How can I get this done?

Comment: Hint: `.{67}` will match anything for 67 characters. What have *you* tried so far? Use a site like http://regexr.com/ to try this.

Comment: Did you already decide where you want to run this regex ? A tool or programming language ? And you will not need regex magic to do this if you simply need to compare two characters at a fixed location.

Comment: I honestly haven't try anything so far. Bacause I simply don't know how to start with this. So I also haven't any idea where I have to run the regex. Something easy accessible I suppose?
I've manually edited one of my files where I kept 70 lines out of a 13000, which took me a long time to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex matches that string from position 67 to 70:

`^.{66}772.*$`

There are various ways to remove lines based on this regex, such as using `grep` with the `-v` flag. It depends on the tool you're using.

Comment: I tried this in command line in Windows: type test.txt | findstr /x ^.{66}772.*$, but it doesn't do a thing. I tried as well with 65 and 67, and with '772', but non of my tries did output something. Maybe command line in Windows isn't the best thing to use?

Comment: I would not use findstr, either I would download `grep` for Windows or use Powershell. 

I got it to work in Powershell like this: `Select-String -n "^.{66}772.*$" .\input.txt`

The `-n` inverts the match. More details here: https://communary.wordpress.com/2014/11/10/grep-the-powershell-way/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I try to use your solution in Powershell, it still returns all lines, instead of the ones I need.

Comment: Select-String "^.{67}772.*$" test.txt, this returned the lines I needed.

Comment: Aha, I understood your question so that you wanted to ignore those lines. But good to know that it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You are a lifesaver!